# Duplicate without accepted or upvoted answer

Tags: support, specific-question

I wanted to close vote [Custom Posts Types as Custom Fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120233) as duplicate of [How to make a relationship between books and authors?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89134), but the system says it's not possible.

[image]

I know this is the default behavior and never gave much thought, but recently I voted to close [a *self-duplicated* Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19612882) in Stack Overflow and there was no restriction, even if the duplicate Q had *no answer*.

Why the difference of treatment?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "says it's not possible"? Which message did you get at which stage of the process?

Comment: Yep, missing a snapshot, updated now.

Comment: See [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question)

Comment: @toscho, ook, that lead me to another that I think [has the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933): *`"...with the exception of questions from the same author..."`*

Comment: Thx to the "anonymous" upvoter, finally I could cast the close vote :)

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to close a duplicate that has no upvotes or accepted answer is the default behavior. The [following feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question) was [status-declined](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined):

> [image]

And the exception is outlined in this [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate):

> [image]